# ACTION_GET_CONTENT doesn't show all videos

Tags: android, android-intent, mime-types

I'm using ACTION_GET_CONTENT to pick one of the videos on the mobile phone:

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("video/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_VIDEO);
```

Unfortunately, sometimes it only shows a subset of the existing video files on the phone, especially not the latest ones. The video files exist but they're not shown in the gallery. Phone is an HTC Incredible S with Android 4.0.4.

Is there maybe a way to refresh the gallery or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app creating the media file is responsible for updating the `MediaStore`, such as via [`MediaScannerConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html) and `scanFile()`, or by sending a `ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` broadcast.

If there's an app on the Incredible S that fails to do this, that's the app's fault, and there's not a ton that you can do about it.